# Islamic Date (Hijiri)

Tags: datetime, hijri

Does anybody know of a way to display the current date using the Islamic (Hajiri) date? Preferrably in PHP and/or Javascript.

Specifically in this format? "10 Safar, 1442"

I have been looking and looking and looking. I can find others using it, and when I search for "display Hajiri date", I get a bunch of sites about Muslim dating... not what I'm looking for, obviously.

I don't need anything special, just the date according to the location of the visitor to a site.

Comment: Note that, depending on location and local traditions, it may be technically impossible to reliably determine the Hijri date algorithmically. For most Muslim communities, the start of the new month is officially determined by a human sighting (or failing to sight) the new crescent moon at sunset. There are various approximations, some simpler, and some that take into account many of the complexities of weather and global position to try and accurately predict what will be determined by the local authorities in a given region, but it comes down to an uncalculatable human event.

Comment: Well, I figured since it's based on lunar cycles, that it could just be calculated as such. I'm not looking for exact times anyway, especially since I know our year isn't a whole number, etc. I've seen other websites with what I'm looking for... I just wish I could figure out how they did it. Viewing source only shows me the end-content (the date itself), so I can't even attempt to reverse engineer.

Comment: Other lunar and lunisolar calendars are based on either a fixed arithmetic approximation of the lunar cycle (like the Hebrew calendar) or the actual time of the lunar conjunction (like the modern Chinese calendar); those can be calculated. It's the explicit dependency on human observation that makes the Islamic case different. But see the other answer - the Saudis use a computed calendar, and a growing number of communities are following them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Hijri Javascript library for Moment.js (https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/calendar/islamic-calendar/); a quick Google for 'hijri calendar php' turns up a number of libraries for that language as well.

If you're interested in understanding how they work, perhaps implementing your own solution, I recommend the book [*Calendrical Calculations* by Reingold and Dershowitz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107683165), which has a chapter on the Islamic calendar, and includes formulas that can be used to approximate it. That includes an attempt at observational accuracy that uses some relatively complex astronomical equations to compute the time of the lunar conjunction with a high degree of precision for dates around the present. The book comes with source code too, albeit in Lisp (the book grew out of the original implementation of the Hebrew calendar for Emacs by one of the authors).

Comment: I saw that as well, but I'm not trying to implement an entire calendar. I'm trying to have just a one-liner as I mentioned in my original post. And I would love to use Shakeel's method, but I don't know Python. I've always focused more on PHP. I know it can be done because I've seen it, I just can't figure out how to do it myself unless I manually code it for every single day for an entire year and then have to update it every year. Which I'd much rather not do.

Answer (score 3):

You must check [this library](https://hijri-converter.readthedocs.io/#usage-examples).
They claim
"*A Python package to convert accurately between Hijri and Gregorian dates using the Umm al-Qura calendar of Saudi Arabia.*"

```
>> from hijri_converter import convert
>>> hijri = convert.Gregorian(1982, 12, 2).to_hijri() 
>>> hijri.datetuple() 
(1403, 2, 17) 
>>> hijri.dmyformat()
 '17/02/1403'
 >>> hijri.month_name()
 'Safar' 
>>> hijri.day_name() 
'Thursday' 
>>> hijri.notation() 
'AH'
```

Comment: I don't really know anything about Python, but I'll try it out, if I can.

Comment: As the comment says, this library implements the Umm al-Qura calendar of Saudi Arabia, which is the rare official calculated calendar. But you might want to ensure that your users accept that calendar before offering it up as "the" Hijri date.

Comment: See https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura.htm.

Comment: @JakobGlantz   The Umm al-Qura calendar is already built into Javascript. Use the Unicode `u-ca-islamic-umalqura` to select it. This is the most modern Islamic calendar and is mostly used in Europe and North America and the Middle East.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to display the Hijri Date in the format requested given a Gregorian Date.

```js
function myHijriDateFormat(date) {
let startDate= new Date(date),
    c= 'en-u-ca-islamic-umalqura-nu-latn',  // use 'islamic-umalqura' calendar for the islamic date
    n='numeric',
    iDay  =new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{day  :n}).format(startDate),
    iMonth=new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{month:'long'}).format(startDate),
    iYear =new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{year :n}).format(startDate).split(" ")[0];

    return iDay+" "+iMonth+", "+iYear;
}
    console.log(myHijriDateFormat(new Date(Date.now()))); // today's date
    console.log(myHijriDateFormat("2022-04-02"));         // first Ramadan 2022
```